# Sum all numbers in array until a certain value is reached

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm writing a function and this is the last piece of the puzzle, which I thought would be easy to deal with, but after some unsuccessful tinkering with for and while loops, I tried looking it up online and still couldn't find an answer. I came across some obscure and complex solutions, but I think there should be a more straightforward way to solve this. For example, if I have an array

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

And the argument is 10, the function should return 6 (1 + 2 + 3), because the sum of the values should be <= 10 (or whatever number is passed). If the argument is 4, the function should return 3 (1 + 2) and so on.

Comment: is the array guaranteed to be pre-sorted? does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop:

```js
const arg = 10
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9]
let res = 0;
const calc = (arr, limit) => {
  for (num of arr) {
    if (num + res > limit) {
      break;
    }
    res += num;
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(calc(arr, arg))
```

Answer (score 1):

`.reduce()` each current value (`cur`) added to the accumulator (`acc`) and checked vs. the limit (`max`). If `acc + cur` is less than limit then return `acc+ cur`, otherwise return `acc`. Added `.sort()` if the array happens to be out of order, as per Spectric's comment.

```js
const array = [1,2,3,5,6,8];
const mixed = [0,7,3,8,2,1];
const A = 10;
const B = 15;
const closest = (arr, max) => {
  return arr.sort((a, b) => a - b).reduce((acc, cur) => 
    (acc + cur) > max ? acc : (acc + cur));  
}

console.log(closest(array, A));
console.log(closest(array, B));
console.log(closest(mixed, B));
```

Comment: @Spectric you're right, updated thanks.

Comment: OP wants the sum of some of the first few numbers such that it isn't greater than the limit. By sorting it you are potentially introducing incorrect results (e.g., there could be a smaller number at the end of the array).

Comment: You said my solution wouldn't work if the array was out of order ( you deleted your comment?) In that context you are correct because the answer would be different, and by sorting it it isn't incorrect. My answer originally worked as does yours now sequentially. Either way my answer works. Not sure why you deleted your original comment which is contrary to what you're saying ATM.

Comment: Using `reduce` is exactly the pitfall to avoid because it will pass through all items. even if the sum passes the maximum value after 3 items and you still have a million to go. also sorting might not be needed since OP did not specify. I assume the original order matters.

Answer (score 1):

One interesting approach is to realize that we want to do a fold (something like `Array.prototype.reduce`) but one which we can escape early.  The answer from zer00ne does this by choosing to check the condition on every iteration, and just continually returning the accumulator each time the condition is not met.  That's fine for many use-cases, but it would be nice to make it more explicit.

I know of two ways to do this.  One is to have some signal value that we would return -- probably a symbol -- to say, "We're done, just return the accumulator."  The downside is that this function now depends on that external signal value.  It's not terrible, and often might be the right solution. It's not hard to write, and I'll leave it as an exercise.

The other technique is to require the callback to explicitly choose whether to continue the iteration or stop by supplying it with `next` and `done` functions.  If we want to continue, we call `next` with the next accumulator value.  If we're finished, we just call `done`.  Here's a version of that:

```js
const fold = (fn) => (a) => ([x, ...xs]) =>
  x == undefined ? a : fn (a, x, (r) => fold (fn) (r) (xs), () => a)

const sumUpTo = (n) => 
  fold ((a, x, next, done) => a + x > n ? done () : next (a + x)) (0)

console .log (sumUpTo (10) ([1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9])) //=> 6
console .log (sumUpTo (4)  ([1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9])) //=> 3
console .log (sumUpTo (10) ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])) //=> 10
```

`sumUpTo` takes our total value and returns a function that takes a list of numbers.  It does this by calling `fold` using a callback function, the initial value (`0` for a sum), and eventually passing our list of numbers.  That callback does the work we care about.  Then `fold` repeatedly calls it until it runs out of values or `done` is called.

We can break down the one-liner version above to focus specifically on the callback, if it makes it more clear:

```js
const callback = (n) => (a, x, next, done) => 
  a + x > n 
    ? done () 
    : next (a + x)

const sumUpTo = (n) => fold (callback (n)) (0)
```

It's a very elegant pattern, to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way with smallest code footprint:

```js
const dataset = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9]

const getMaxSum = (dataset, max) => {
  var sum = 0, num;
  for( num of dataset ) {
    if( sum + num > max ) break // very important to break once satisfied
    sum += num
  }
  return sum
}

console.log( getMaxSum(dataset, 10) )
console.log( getMaxSum(dataset, 20) )
```